# Pandas: Check True/False if id appears at least 3 times in a particular column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with a column 'ID'. I would like to check if the same id appears in the 'ID' column at least 3 times in the file. If yes, then mark it as `True`, if not then mark it as `False` and add results in a new column in the same dataframe.

my code so far:

```
combined_csv['threeIDs'] = (combined_csv['ID'].value_counts() > 2)
```

the above code adds additional column (threeIDs), however it is empty and doesn't contain True/False results.

Could someone help with this? thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby().transform`:

```
combined_csv['threeIds'] = combined_csv.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('size')>=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
combined_csv['threeIDs'] = combined_csv.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform(lambda x: len(x) > 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do in two steps:

```
df['coundIDs'] = df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('size') # creates a column that counts ID
df['threeIDs'] = np.where(df['countIDs'] > 2, 1,0) # 1 or 0 depending 2 ID's or more
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `map`

```
combined_csv['threeIDs'] = combined_csv['ID'].map((combined_csv['ID'].value_counts() > 2))
```